# I want to automatically create graphs using a plugin according to an SQL query

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Currently I want to make my graph automatically painted with my php code since it does an SQL query and gets required results for graphing.

Code JS:

```
var conteo0=$(".GraficaConteo0").get(0);
    
    
    var total=$(conteo0).text();
    var dataStr="";
    var colorStr="";
    var StrComa=",";
    
    for(var i = 1; i <= total; i++){
    var conteo=$(".GraficaConteo0").get(i);
    var color0=$(".ColorGrafica0").get(i-1);
    var conteoFull=$(conteo).text();
    var ColorFull=$(color0).text();
    dataStr+="\""+conteoFull+"\""+StrComa;
    colorStr+="'"+ColorFull+"'"+StrComa;
    if(i==(total-1)){
    StrComa="";
    }
    
    }

alert(dataStr);

// Pie Chart Example
var ctx = document.getElementById("myPieChart1");
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: [dataStr],
    datasets: [{
      data: [dataStr],
      backgroundColor: [colorStr],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [colorStr],
      hoverBorderColor: "rgba(234, 236, 244, 1)",
    }],
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255,255,255)",
      bodyFontColor: "#858796",
      borderColor: '#dddfeb',
      borderWidth: 1,
      xPadding: 15,
      yPadding: 15,
      displayColors: false,
      caretPadding: 10,
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
  },
});
```

Code PHP:

```
$ConteoGrafica0="";
$grafica0="";
$sqlGrafica = "select count(*) as conteo, campo1 as retornocampo from tabla500 group by campo1";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlGrafica);
$conteo=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      $ConteoGrafica0="<label class='GraficaConteo0 d-none'>".$result->num_rows."</label>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $randomColor = rand(0,12);    
$grafica0.="<span class='mr-2'>
                      <i class='fas fa-circle' style='color:".$arrayGrafica[$randomColor]."'></i>".$row["retornocampo"]."
                    </span>";
$ConteoGrafica0.="<label class='GraficaConteo0 d-none'>".$row["conteo"]."</label>";
$ConteoGrafica0.="<label class='ColorGrafica0 d-none'>".$arrayGrafica[$randomColor]."</label>";
$conteo++;
    }

} else {

$grafica0="Sin Informacion";

}
```

Code HTML5:

```
     <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-5">
              <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Motivos de Cancelacion</h6>
                  <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Card Body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="chart-pie pt-4 pb-2">
                    <canvas id="myPieChart1"></canvas>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mt-4 text-center small">
<?php echo $grafica0; ?>
<?php echo $ConteoGrafica0; ?>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is the following I print in alert (dataStr); and I get "1", "2", "1" and paste it with its respective attribute but the graph is not painted if it is supposed to replace the appropriate values, besides if I copy them from the alert and paste them manually if it works. I use this plugin https://www.chartjs.org/.

Comment: Is the JS code the complete code? Is there a DOMContentReady listener or jQuery ready function? If that is all of the JS, then were is it in the html? Is it included before or after the html snippet shown?

Comment: Sorry! My thoughts got ahead of my typing. That should be: 

Is there a DOMContentLoaded listener or jQuery ready function? 

You may have already known what I was trying to ask, but I just wanted to clarify to avoid confusion.